# How to join columns of year and month in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataset look like this:

```
    Year    Month    Partisan Conflict
0   1981    January  68.944808
1   1981    February 64.907109
2   1981    March    79.058476
3   1981    April    69.324041
4   1981    May      88.194466
```

The data was imported from an excel file.

I am wondering how I can join the columns of year and month with a format like:

```
1981-01
1981-02
...
```

I checked the format of them.

```
type(df.iloc[0]['Month'])
str

type(df.iloc[0]['Year'])
numpy.int64
```

But to add them together is the question I haven't figure out. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Use the datetime package to convert your months into 01,02,... then define a new row adding the both together as strings. str(year) + "-" + str(month)

Comment: Do you want the output to be of type string or datetime? (What do you intend to do with it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First concatenate the `Year` and `Month` column then use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to transform this concatenated column to pandas datetime series then use  [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to convert this datetime series in required format:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Year'].astype(str) + df['Month'], format='%Y%B').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

OR, it is also possible to use `mappings` dictionary to map the `Month` column using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
mappings = {'January': '01', 'February': '02', 'March': '03', 'April': '04', 'May': '05', 'June': '06',
            'July': '07',  'August': '08', 'September': '09', 'Octomber': '10', 'November': '11', 'December': '12'}

df['Date'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Month'].map(mappings)
```

---

```
# print(df)
   Year     Month  Partisan Conflict     Date
0  1981   January          68.944808  1981-01
1  1981  February          64.907109  1981-02
2  1981     March          79.058476  1981-03
3  1981     April          69.324041  1981-04
4  1981       May          88.194466  1981-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try  with below code?

```
Dates = {'Month': ['Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct'], 
        'Year': [2016,2017,2018,2019,2020]} 

df = DataFrame(Dates, columns= ['Month','Year']) 
df1 =  df['Month'].map(str) + '-' + df['Year'].map(str)

print (df1)




Note I just gave an example to resolve the issue.
```

Comment: This is not the format that OP requires, u might need to define the map ``{"January":"01", "February": "02"}`` to get what OP needs